# Use models foreign key _id column as field in django form

Tags: django, django-models, django-forms

When you create a ForeignKey in a django model django also creates a _id column in the database. I'm trying to figure out how to display this value in a django form but can't seem to get it to work. With what I have below the category_id field appears in the form but the value itself doesn't?

**marketplace/models.py**

```
class Category(models.Model):
    category = models.CharField(null=True)
    category_code = models.IntegerField(unique=True)
```

**store/models.py**

```
class Product(models.Model):
    created = models.DateTimeField(default=now)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200, unique=True)
    category = models.ForeignKey('marketplace.Category', blank=True, null=True, to_field='category_code')
```

**store/forms.py**

```
class Form(forms.ModelForm):

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
        super(Form, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
        self.fields['category_id'] = self.instance.category_id

    class Meta:
        model = Product
        fields = ['name', 'created']
```

Comment: your request is unclear to me, what's the difference between what you're trying to do and simply adding `"category"` to your `Form` `fields`?

Comment: category in the Product model represents the category_code in the Category model

Comment: ah, seems like i didn't see the scroll bar :)

Comment: haha not a problem. There are more fields in the Category model I just cut them down for simplicity sake.

Comment: quoting the docs:
"For fields like ForeignKey that map to model instances, defaults should  be the value of the field they reference (pk unless to_field is set) instead  of model instances."
so the relation category_id shouldn't exist?

Comment: kinda curious, i never had to use the `to_field` attr, have you tried `self.instance.category.id` instead?

Comment: no I haven't but wouldn't that reference the primary key in the Category model? I'll give it a shot anyway and see what happens.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/123811/discussion-between-moku-and-hassenpy).